# 18.04 - Thinkpad X1 Carbon 6th Gen - Intel 8265: WiFi not working

Tags: drivers, 18.04

I got a Thinkpad X1 Carbon 6th Gen with Ubuntu 18.04 installed and when I open Settings I'm getting the following error:

```
No Wi-Fi Adapter found
```

The WiFi card is [Intel® Dual Band Wireless-AC 8265](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/product-briefs/dual-band-wireless-ac-8265-brief.pdf)

```
$ uname -a
Linux XXXXXXXX 4.15.0-58-generic #64-Ubuntu SMP Tue Aug 6 11:12:41 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I've installed the latest firmware updates with `fwupd`.

Relevant dumps:

- `sudo lshw` https://pastebin.com/n71K6VTm
- `lsusb -v` https://pastebin.com/ZrPrZuE0
- `lspci -v` https://pastebin.com/ABTewhaT
- `dmesg` https://pastebin.com/kmEmp9c9

Please let me know if any other information will be of assistance.